# app can't distinguish screen size

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, nslog

in AppDelegate.h file, I add

```
#define iPhone5 ([UIScreen instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(currentMode)] ? CGSizeEqualToSize(CGSizeMake(640, 1136), [[UIScreen mainScreen] currentMode].size) : NO)
```

and in AppDelegate.m file, I add

```
if (iPhone5) {
    NSLog(@"iPhone5/5s")
}
else {
    NSLog(@"not iPhone5/5s");
}
```

but it shows log `not iPhone5/5s` when I run this project in iPhone 5 or 5s, in my project, I just add cocoapods, and open this project file that cocoapods created(projectname.xcworkspace).
BTW, it runs right if i create a new project without using cocoapods, so how can i fix it?

Comment: Have you use iPhone5 variable name anywhere else? Please check

Comment: #define IS_IPHONE_5 ( fabs( ( double )[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height - ( double )568 ) < DBL_EPSILON )
try this one

Comment: @KaranDua i think, the question isn't on `#define iPhone5..` here, i can use this code in other project, it runs well, but only this project that i use cocoapods can't runs right. your code is also doesn't work. thanks

Comment: @KaranDua i try to get height by using `[[UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height`, and always get 480, not 568, both in real device(iPhone 5) and in simulator(4-inch).

Comment: Your app is not iPhone 5 compatible.

Comment: @KaranDua i don't think so, i create this project by using xcode 5.1.1 (the latest version) on osx 10.9.3, and i can run it well before until i add cocoapods to this project.

Comment: Have You added the Default-568h@2x.png to your project?

Comment: @KaranDua thanks, i am really forgetting this. so shy.